# SQL query performance? more as double

Tags: sql, performance, select, mariadb

**-mariadb on a linux 4core 8 gig ram vps beast**

i try the following select statement.

```
SELECT * 
from Sensorwerte 
WHERE (Datum>='2023-10-01 00' 
    and Datum <='2023-10-15 00' 
    AND (Datum LIKE '%15:00.000')) 
    AND SensorNr=3004 
ORDER BY ID DESC;

/* Betroffene Zeilen: 0  Gefundene Zeilen: 335  Warnungen: 0  Dauer von 1 Abfrage: 2,313 Sek. */
```

answer after 2,3sec for 15 days

but for 30 days:

```
SELECT * 
from Sensorwerte 
WHERE (Datum>='2023-10-01 00' 
    and Datum <='2023-10-30 00'
    AND (Datum LIKE '%15:00.000')) 
    AND SensorNr=3004 
ORDER BY ID DESC;

/* Betroffene Zeilen: 0  Gefundene Zeilen: 696  Warnungen: 0  Dauer von 1 Abfrage: 29,594 Sek. (+ 55,297 Sek. Netzwerk) */
```

answer after 84sec for 30 days

i mean the double is ok ~5sec but 84sec is not ok.
whats wrong or how i can tune this on server or sql select?

have you any idea?

```
SELECT * 
from Sensorwerte 
WHERE (Datum>='2023-10-01 00'
       AND Datum <='2023-10-15 00')
       AND SensorNr=3004 
ORDER BY ID DESC;
```

without **LIKE** for 15 days --> 14sec

**show create table Sensorwerte**

```
CREATE TABLE `Sensorwerte` 
    (`ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     `Datum` datetime(3) NOT NULL,
     `SensorNr` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
     `Wert` decimal(15,5) DEFAULT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
      KEY `Zeit` (`Datum`)) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=52208193 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci
```

**analyze-statement answer**

```
select_type=simple,
table=sensorwerte, 
type=index, 
possible_keys=zeit, 
key=primary, 
key_len=4, 
ref=(NULL), 
rows=48615830, 
r_rows=51973599.00, 
filtered=31,65, 
r_filtered=0, 
extra=using where
```

Comment: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/analyze-statement/ What does the execution plan show?

Comment: Yes you need to profile, but one obvious potential issue is that this type of query can not use an index:  Datum LIKE '%15:00.000'.  So it could be that there are just many more rows that need to be filtered on that DATUM criteria in the 2nd result set.

Comment: analyze anwer:    select_type=simple , table=sensorwerte, type=index, possible_keys=zeit, key=primary, key_len=4, ref=(NULL), rows=48615830, r_rows=51973599.00, filtered=31,65, r_filtered=0, extra=using where

Comment: An index on `(SensorNr,Datum)` will be aid the query all criteria except for the `Datum LIKE` criteria. Edit the question to add further information. There isn't sufficient space in the comments.

Comment: What is the datatype of `Datum`? This will be more efficient if it's a `DATETIME` rather than a character string.

Comment: datatype = DATETIME

Comment: without LIKE for 15 days ~14 sec.

Comment: please edit your question to show (as text, not images) output of `show create table Sensorwerte` and `explain select ...` for both selects

Comment: ok -->show create table Sensorwerte -->see question

Comment: The query looks for readings taken on exactly 3;m on certain days?

Comment: Is fetching by time (or time range) a common query? [GENERATED COLUMN](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/generated-columns/) extracting the column, with a `(SensorNr,DatumTime,Datum)` index could help in this case.

Answer (score 1):

For most queries of Sensor data, this is beneficial

```
INDEX(SensorNr, Datum)
```

(And remove this if you also have it:  `INDEX(SensorNr)`)

More:  https://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_sensor

Answer (score 0):

Add an index. As `SensorNr` is a fixed value put it before `Datum`. Then the query can use this index for all parts of the search.

```
ALTER TABLE Sensorwerte ADD KEY newKey(`SensorNr`,`Datum`);
```

Use [datetime functions](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/date-time-functions/) like `time(Datum) = '15:00.000'` when processing dates rather than string functions.

Query plan:

```
MariaDB [test]> explain format=json  SELECT *  from Sensorwerte  WHERE (Datum>='2023-10-01'      and Datum <='2023-10-30 00'     AND time(Datum) = '15:00.000') and SensorNr=3007    ORDER BY ID DESC\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
EXPLAIN: {
  "query_block": {
    "select_id": 1,
    "read_sorted_file": {
      "filesort": {
        "sort_key": "Sensorwerte.`ID` desc",
        "table": {
          "table_name": "Sensorwerte",
          "access_type": "range",
          "possible_keys": ["newKey", "Zeit"],
          "key": "newKey",
          "key_length": "9",
          "used_key_parts": ["SensorNr", "Datum"],
          "rows": 69,
          "filtered": 0.0069,
          "index_condition": "Sensorwerte.SensorNr = 3007 and Sensorwerte.Datum >= '2023-10-01' and Sensorwerte.Datum <= '2023-10-30 00' and cast(Sensorwerte.Datum as time(3)) = '15:00.000'"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
1 row in set (0.002 sec)
```